# WiFi connections are not visible in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, adapter

I have a WiFi adapter for my PC which works fine in windows,
but it does not show any WiFi connections nearby it in Ubuntu

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 2c:f0:5d:0b:7e:10
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df204000-df204fff memory:df200000-df203fff   *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx00e04c818802
       serial: 00:e0:4c:81:88:02
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic multicast=yes wireless=unassociated  
*-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: usb0
       serial: a2:64:97:3c:94:2d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-40-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.57.100 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller is my USB WiFi adapter
I think it is a driver problem i have tried installing some,

following is the output of `dkms status`

```
rtl8188fu/1.0, 5.15.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8188fu/1.0, 5.15.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1, 5.15.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1, 5.15.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 22d9:202c OPPO Electronics Corp. realme Phone
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1903:8328 Generic HD camera 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please help me with it, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the Wi-Fi adapter? Is it a USB adapter? `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller` is NOT a Wi-Fi adapter. It is a built in Ethernet device.

Comment: I suspect that you made an error in posting above and that this is the wireless: *logical name: wlx00e04c818802* Please check and edit as needed.

Comment: Please show us the result of: `sudo modprobe -r r8188eu` and: `sudo modprobe rtl8188fu` and finally: `nmcli device wifi list` Redact the MAC addresses with xxxx if any.

Comment: Hey @chili555 problem solved bro! Thanks a lot

Comment: Please confirm that r8188eu does *not* work but rtl8188fu *does* work. Also please confirm that the sequence of commands above does not survive a reboot. If true, I shall propose an answer.

Comment: yes you are right this is not a permanent solution, after i shutdown and start my pc, the problem ran again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s blacklist the built-in driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist r8188eu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo rtl8188fu >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thank You very much! you saved me